# How to remove gesture for RESideMenu from UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, residemenu

I want to remove gesture recogniser for RESidemenu controller form particular UIView. how can we remove it.

i have removed all gestures from view, but its not working fine.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in self.view.gestureRecognizers)
{
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}
```

Comment: Did you try `panGestureEnabled`

Comment: @Rajesh, yes i did that. but its not working.